# JHipster hangs for every command

Tags: jhipster

I'm trying to start project with JHipster 6. Unfortunately every single command I give cause long (3-10 Minutes) lag.

E.g. when I type

```
jhipster --verbose
INFO! Using JHipster version installed globally
```

I have to wait until something will appear on the screen. Is there any possiblity to enable tracing?

OS: Win10 64bit
node: 12.16.2
npm: 6.14.4

Comment: Looks like a networking issue, are you behind a corporate firewall or proxy ? You could try to run the command under node debugger to find which call is blocking or use network tracing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the bug https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/11617
Already fixed in https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/11618 and will be available in a newer versions